# What folder is the in app title stored in, in an android app? The title that comes up as soon as you launch the app, in the main menu

Tags: android

Wondering which of the main folders contains the main title of the app, like you launch tinder for example and then it says "Tinder" in bold red on top.

Comment: If I could understand your question the string of app name is in `string.xml` in res folder!

Comment: The title of an activity may or may not be the same as the title of the app.  The app title is set by the [application label](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label) attribute in the manifest.

Answer (score 3):

The main title of the APP as you mention is not present as a separate file. Rather, it is present along with all other "Important Strings" in your "strings.xml" file.

A typical AndroidManifest.xml will have the following in it:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <activity
         .
         .
         .
    </activity>
</application>
```

As you can see, the andoid:label is what sets the app name on top and this name is defined in a variable called "app_name" present in the strings.xml file. You can find the "strings.xml" file in the "res" folder.

Answer (score 1):

So basically on your android app module inside your android studio project the files will be organized this way

```
-root of your module(normally called app)
  ->build: all files generated after building will be here
  ->src: all source files and resources used in the app will be here
    ->main: all source related to your main build flavour
      ->assets : Assets such as fonts go here
      ->java: all java source files go here
      ->res: all resources files such as strings, layouts, drawables go
```

here.

So under the res folder you will have a values folder with a file called **strings.xml**. 
In this file you can define strings that you can then access from your code or other resource files through their ID's.

By default when the project is created there is a string called app_name that has the value of your application name(the same that shows below your app icon in the homescreen)

So assuming you are talking about that the top bar you are talking about is a toolbar I would say that the title was just set to this value of app_name or it is simply a custom image there.

If you would like to read more about string resources and localization:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: How would one change a preexisting Title image what would be the detailed steps to do so?

Comment: So assuming it is an image, first of all you would need to have the image for the right screen sizes if using png or svg. Then one approach would be to set this image as the Toolbar home action icon that you would normally set to be the back button or navigation drawer icon. You could start by adding simple title and follow this link to get to learn in details what I just tried to explain: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html